# Permissions for a magento developer user account

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I am hiring a developer to install and configure Magento 2.0 on my Amazon EC2 Linux server.  I am new to Linux and Magento.  I have given them SSH access and created a [magento file system owner](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html) user.  They can login to the server with SSH but they are saying they don't have `sudo` or `sudo su` privileges. I added them to the `wheel` group the following line is in the `sudoers` file

```
%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I need some guidance on what to do.  I want them to  be able to do everything they need to install and configure magento.

Answer (score 2):

usually you need to ask them to generate their own ssh key, apart from your master EC2 ssh key, and you add its public part to the server and they can work.

public part of
your master ssh key already must be here : `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
this is how you connect , right?

Comment: That's not the problem I'm having.  They can access the server using the SSH keys already.  They said that they aren't able to use `sudo su` with the account.  How to I set up the proper permissions for a user to be able to install and configure magento on amazon EC2 Linux?  Is there a group I add them to?  Or just give them root access?

Comment: ok, then we need to know in which group they are and where is located their ssh key?